# pegar data PHP, com condições

Tags: php, html, data

Gostaria de pegar a data que o usuário entrou como base para a informação que ele vai selecionar.
Vão ser 4 opções de data, mas as condições são: se o usuário selecionar um dia que já passou, ele vai me enviar o dia com o mês seguinte.
Exp.: Hoje dia 18/03/2019
ele pode escolher entre: dia 5; dia 10; dia 15; dia 20;
se ele escolher dia 5, 5<18, me envia a data 05/04/2019;
se ele escolher dia 20, 20>18, me envia a data 20/03/2019;

Até agora eu fiz esse PHP, porem ele esta retornando 0 nas datas, gostaria da ajuda de vocês para achar o que pode esta dando errado.

```
<?php
$data = date('d/m/Y');
$dataS = explode("/", $data);
$dia = $dataS[0];
$mes = $dataS[1];
$ano = $dataS[2];
?>
<?php
if($dia > 5){
    $mes = date('m',strtotime('+1month'));
    $d5 = $mes;
}
elseif($dia <= 5){
    $mes = $dataS[1];
    $d5 = $mes;
}
?>
<?php
if($dia > 10){
    $mes = date('m',strtotime('+1month'));
}
elseif($dia <= 10){
    $mes = $dataS[1];
    $d10 = $mes;
}
?>
<?php
if($dia > 15){
    $mes = date('m',strtotime('+1month'));
}
elseif($dia <= 15){
    $mes = $dataS[1];
    $d15 = $mes;
}
?>
<?php
if($dia > 20){
    $mes = date('m',strtotime('+1month'));
}
elseif($dia <= 20){
    $mes = $dataS[1];
    $d20 = $mes;
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>
Data hoje:<?php echo $data ?>;<br>Dia:<?php echo $data[0] ?>;<br>Mês:<?php echo $data[1] ?>;<br>Ano:<?php echo $data[2] ?>;<br>Dia 5:<?php echo $d5 ?>;<br>Dia 10:<?php echo $d10 ?>;<br>Dia 15<?php echo $d15 ?>;<br>Dia 20<?php echo $d20 ?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$dia = $data[0]`, não deveria ser `$dataS[0]` no lugar de `$data[0]`?

Comment: sim, eu vi, já corrigi, porem o erro ainda se mantem

Comment: vou atualizar o post, pra como esta agora.

Comment: agora quando testo ele, me devolve a data, porem o 'explode' não esta indo corretamente, ele devolve "1"; "8", "/". Em vez de "18", "03", "2019".

Comment: O `explode` funciona sim: https://ideone.com/gPxyGx

Comment: como vc pode ver, fiz da msm maneira no que mostrei na pergunta...e não funcionou

Answer (score -1):

o problema foi que o 'explode()' nao funciona corretamente em 'date()'.
então troquei por 3 'date()'.

```html
<?php
$dataD = date('d');
$dataM = date('m');
$dataY = date('Y');
?>
<?php
if($dataD > 5){
 $mes = date('m',strtotime('+1month'));
 $d5 = $mes;
}
elseif($dataD <= 5){
 $mes = $dataM;
 $d5 = $mes;
}
?>
<?php
if($dataD > 10){
 $mes = date('m',strtotime('+1month'));
 $d10 = $mes;
}
elseif($dataD <= 10){
 $mes = $dataM;
 $d10 = $mes;
}
?>
<?php
if($dataD > 15){
 $mes = date('m',strtotime('+1month'));
 $d15 = $mes;
}
elseif($dataD <= 15){
 $mes = $dataM;
 $d15 = $mes;
}
?>
<?php
if($dataD > 20){
 $mes = date('m',strtotime('+1month'));
}
elseif($dataD <= 20){
 $mes = $dataM;
 $d20 = $mes;
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>
Data hoje:<?php echo $data ?>;<br>Dia 5:<?php echo $d5 ?>;<br>Dia 10:<?php echo $d10 ?>;<br>Dia 15:<?php echo $d15 ?>;<br>Dia 20:<?php echo $d20 ?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```